# PHP converting WIM date format

Tags: php, .net, windows

I am writing a wrapper library for [WIM files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Format) (long story), but I have been having difficulty with the dates encoded in it. The format is:

```
[creationtime] => Array
                        (
                            [highpart] => 0x01CA0446
                            [lowpart] => 0x8E44DCAF
                        )
```

This format is inside the WIM file XML.
I have tried every date decoding technique I can think of!
Any ideas would be much appreciated.
The only things I have to go on are things related to Long Integers and WIN32 DateTime... But no luck so far.

Comment: They have no relevance as `0x01CA0446=30016582` and `0x8E44DCAF=2386877615`

Comment: part of a stamp perhaps? but by the code you've provided it's impossible to tell

Comment: I know. That is all I have to go on, though :( I assume there must be a relevance, although I have no idea what. Trust Microsoft to over-complicate a simple time stamp...

Comment: [One of Microsoft's date formats uses 64-bit values to represent the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284%28VS.85%29.aspx). Have you tried that?

Comment: @DCoder if we're correct (I just added the same thing as an answer) please make yours an answer too and I will remove mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`liCreationTime` is defined as `LARGE_INTEGER` in the WIM spec (I downloaded from MS)

This looked to me like it would be similar (if not the same) as a timestamp returned by `QueryPerformanceCounter` - which thankfully makes things very simple!

I did this using a calculator and command line PHP, you'll have to implement the code yourself.

Take your high and low parts and turn them into a single 64bit value.

> 0x01CA04468E44DCAF -> 128920240414579887

Divide that by 100000000

> 1289202404

Use it as the input to `date()`

```
php -r "var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1289202404));"
string(19) "2010-11-08 07:46:44"
```

**Edit:**

Or maybe I just got lucky.

If it is the number of nanoseconds since 1601, as other answers seem to indicate, you can use a slightly different calculation.

```
php -r "var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (128920240414579887/100000000)-41651963));"
string(19) "2009-07-14 05:47:21"
```

Comment: How did you convert the hex to the decimal (I tried PHP's "hexdec" and it returned a minus)

Comment: Do you have the correct date as a reference? - And are you using a 64 bit version of PHP?

Comment: I have just created a WIM file for reference (14/09/2012) and it is now certain that highpart is date and lowpart is time. I created it at around 08:56/57 AM. [highpart] => 0x01CD924E, [lowpart] => 0x899676EB. I tested your code with this and it returned 2011 and the wrong time :(

Comment: @Stufur: Based on that reference file you have, this should give you a starting point: `$hi = '01CD924E'; $lo = '899676EB'; $cmd = sprintf('w32tm /ntte 0x%s%s', $hi, $lo
); $out = array(); exec($cmd, $out); var_dump(implode("\n", $out));'`. [w32tm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491016.aspx) is a Windows command line tool that can convert these timestamps to readable formats.

Comment: Thanks @DCoder! That is perfect! This is a Windows-only application for a number of reasons, so there is no problem with using a Windows CMD tool. (I already use 4 or 5 in it!)

Comment: @Mindcore: If you're using a 32bit PHP, you might run into problems with 64bit integers. Just saying that his could play a role for the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they might be something to do with the c/c++ FILETIME structure

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284(v=vs.85).aspx